# How to read the version of PDF document from the Document properties using vba

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to read each value in the document properties in a pdf document.
Refer below screen: in screen to get the value of PDF Producer i use code `acroPDDoc.GetInfo( "Producer" )`
code snip:

```
Set acroPDDoc = acroAVDoc.GetPDDoc()
Set acroAVDoc = CreateObject( "AcroExch.AVDoc" )

If acroAVDoc.Open( gPDFPath, Empty ) Then



If acroAVDoc.IsValid = False Then ExitTest()



Set acroPDDoc = acroAVDoc.GetPDDoc()

Print "Info::Producer ---> " & acroPDDoc.GetInfo( "Producer" )

Print "Info::Version ---> " & acroPDDoc.GetInfo( "Version")
```

where i get the right result for pdf Producer but no data for PDF version. Any help around this would be nice.
[image: pdf document properties]

Comment: Maybe check out https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-sdk-discussions/programatic-access-to-pdf-meta-data-including-xmp-metadata-using-excel-vba/td-p/12537754